# Rails fetch different current time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am trying to apply a cron job in such manner that  I need to fetch 3 countries time and check whether it is 6 am or not If it is according to that country so a particular service should run.I am using task scheduler for that Every time it is printing china only

> my_task_schedular.rb

```
       s = Rufus::Scheduler.new
s.every '1m' do 

    Tzone.each do |zone|

        time = TZInfo::Timezone.get(zone)

         time.now.strftime("%I:%M")

    end
```

> application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Shivam
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
     config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you need to check if it's 6 am on a selected timezone you can use this:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Asia/Kolkata').hour == 6
```

As stated in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-hour), hour will return the hour of the day (0..23)

Remember that `Time.zone` on gives the current Time zone, where your machine is, also you can configure your Rails app to have a Timezone and your machine had a completely different timezone, but you can get in trouble in the datasources.

Comment: SO i need to do your way only for every country ??? And how will i find am or pm?

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_time_zone` method to acquire proper time. For this moment we have:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone
 => Wed, 30 Dec 2015 10:19:41 CET +01:00
```

And for another zones:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Asia/Kolkata')
 => Wed, 30 Dec 2015 14:50:03 IST +05:30

Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 => Wed, 30 Dec 2015 04:20:31 EST -05:00
```

Comment: hey i am able to fetch time but I am not able to compare time For eg if it is 5 am in us or in china so my cron job service should run so is there any way to do so?

Comment: @user5729333 Let me know if I understand you properly: you do not want check if there is a time in a zone, but need to run a cron job in a specified time (e.g. 6 AM) in a specified time zone, right?

Comment: My problem is I am setting a cron job in a way that whenever it will be 5 pm in that particular country my service will run .For eg if it will 5pm is us my service will run if it will be 5 pm in india my service will run ..

Comment: @user5729333 So you can do a cron job executed hourly and loop through supported zones checking if there is currently proper time in zone using `in_time_zone` as proposed. Paulo in his answer suggested how to get the hour.